# Ms - Sql using cross select?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select

I have some query with group by. I also have couple school Id min and max earning. I grouped and i want to calculate total earning. but i don t know how can i use cross select.

```
 RowId    SchoolId  month   maxEarning   minEarning

 1         1        1        1000         900
 2         1        2        2000         300 
 3         1        3        1500         750
 4         2        1        2000         500
 5         2        2        1500         1000
 6         3        1        2000         1000
```

answer would be

```
  school id 1 ==> diff second month and first month 2000 - 900 = 1100
  school id 1 ==> diff third month and second month 1500 - 300 = 1200
  school id 2 ==> diff second month and first month 1500 - 500 = 1000
  school id 3 ==> diff first month only 2000
```

finally i want to see like :

```
   RowId    SchoolId  month   maxEarning   minEarning    DiffWithGroup
    1         1        1        1000         900         1000
    2         1        2        2000         300         1100
    3         1        3        1500         750         1200
    4         2        1        2000         500         2000
    5         2        2        1500         1000        1000
    6         3        1        2000         1000        2000
```

Comment: are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: Microsoft Sql Server

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LAG` analytic function is one option if your version of SQL Server supports it:

```
SELECT
    RowId, SchoolId, month, maxEarning, minEarning,
    maxEarning - LAG(minEarning, 1, 0) OVER
        (PARTITION BY SchoolId ORDER BY month) AS DiffWithGroup
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY RowId;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

We can use `LAG` function to do this -

```
select
    RowId,
    SchoolId,
    month,
    maxEarning,
    minEarning,
    DiffWithGroup = (maxEarning - lag(minEarning,1,0) over(partition by SchoolId order by month))
from YourTableName
```

Check about this function here - [LAG TSQL Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

for SQL Server 2012 and later, you can use LAG()

```
select  *,
        maxEarning - isnull(LAG(minEarning) over (partition by SchoolId 
                                                      order by month), 0) as DiffWithGroup
from    your_table
```